# Typescript/CommonJS Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, commonjs, transpiler

quick typescript/commonjs question: I’m stuck on this error and have tried changing type:module in config.json and various module:es2020, esnext, … but am still stuck with this. Any known quick fixes?

here is my repo with the ts.config.json. the .js is in the build directory not uploaded to git:

https://github.com/PlasmNetwork/dusty-faucet/tree/main/app

[image: code]

Comment: could you please share your tsconfig.json file? is it possible that your files are not "included" in the tsconfig?

Comment: @Liad Yes, just added now!